# Why is my hr tag behaving differently in two places?

Tags: html, class

I'm using the same class selector but I don't understand why it's behaving differently.

Here's my website:

http://violetoeuvre.com/

In the first instance the margins are fine; in the second case, not.

```
<!-- Side Navigation__________________________________-->
    <div class="side_nav_wrapper">
        <div class="side_nav_photos" id="side_wrapper_text">photos</div>
        <div class="side_nav_about" id="side_wrapper_text">about</div>
        <div class="side_nav_writing" id="side_wrapper_text" >writing</div>
        <div class="side_nav_contact" id="side_wrapper_text">contact</div>
    </div>

<!-- CONTENT____________________________________________-->

<div class="content_wrapper">

<!-- Photo __________________________________________-->

    <div class="home_photo">
    </div>

    <hr class="line">
<!-- About___________________________________________________-->

    <div class="home_text">
        <p>Emma Carmichael is a writer and editor based in Brooklyn, NY, although she hails from Brattleboro, VT. Emma graduated from Vassar College in 2010 with a degree in Urban Studies; the theme of her thesis about contextualizing female rappers, ETC.
    </p>
    </div>

    <hr class="line">
```

(Also, I can't figure out why this class isn't applying:)

```
#side_wrapper_text a:link{
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:rgba (255,255,255,1);
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;

}

<div class="side_nav_wrapper">
        <div class="side_nav_photos" id="side_wrapper_text">photos</div>
        <div class="side_nav_about" id="side_wrapper_text">about</div>
        <div class="side_nav_writing" id="side_wrapper_text" >writing</div>
        <div class="side_nav_contact" id="side_wrapper_text">contact</div>
    </div>
```

THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class `home_text` applies the attribute `float: left;`, which takes that `<div>` element out of the document flow. if you remove that float attribute, you'll see that the `<div>`  respects the document flow again, and doesn't lay on top of the `<hr>`'s margins.

alternatively, you could use `clear: both` to fix this like this:

in your css file:

```
.clearer { clear: both; }
```

in your markup:

```
<div class='home_text'>...</div>
<div class='clearer'></div>
<hr class='line' />
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I take away the float:left for home_text, won't the element behave strangely? So, to fix this, i add the clearer div AFTER the home text, and add the class to my css?

Comment: Then you messed something up. Adding `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` after `<div class="home_text"></div>` fixes your margin issue.

Comment: Hi Mike - I did just that, I still don't understand why it's not working. 
I added <div style="clear: both;" class="clearer"></div>
 <hr class="line">
immediately after the home_text in my html. 
In my css I added .clearer { clear: both; }
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a clear:both to .line if you are going to float things

Also you really should use a class and not an id if it is going to be in more than on place on a page (like #side_wrapper_text ) also you don't have any links for it to apply to.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused by what you mean. Doesn't the clear need its own class?

Comment: No you can do something like .line{width:400px;clear:both;}. A lot of people end up defining a class .clear{clear:both;} which they then use everywhere, but you certainly don't have to

Answer (score 0):

Haven't taken a stab at the first part of your question, but the second is twofold:

1. ID's are to be unique on a page, yet you have four div's with an id of 'side_wrapper_text'
2. Secondly, you have no anchor tags (a) for the CSS to apply to.

You probably want something like this instead:

```
#side_wrapper_text a:link{
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100; 
    color:rgba (255,255,255,1);
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing:0.2em;

}

<div id="side_wrapper_text" class="side_nav_wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="side_nav_photos">photos</a>
    <a href="#" class="side_nav_about">about</a>
    <a href="#" class="side_nav_writing">writing</a>
    <a href="#" class="side_nav_contact">contact</a>
</div>
```